# How to get objects in a razor template in Tridion?

Tags: tridion, razor-mediator

I am writing a common Razor TBB, which will use in Component Template and Page template as per my requirement.

So that, I need a Page and Component object in the razor TBB according to applying TBB on Page Template and component Template

My requirement to display/use the metadata field values from Page/Component in specific area of the page.

That's why, i want to access metadata values by the object but unable to get the object,

Please also follow-up my comments with Frank.

Can any one suggest me?

Comment: Actually, i am creating a common TBB for component and page, for access the Metadata values. I need to access metadata values from component and page, and afterward use these values to render the common html, and want to accessed by Package.Output

Comment: Could you please edit your question and supply in more detail what you want to do, what you did, and where you are stuck?

Comment: Great info in the follow-up comments, +1 to moving them into the original question. I'd gladly vote up the full story as it may help others. The mediator author also asks implementors to email him with feedback issues. I'd also recommend working with him and/or submitting issues on the Google Code repository.

Answer (score 8):

Did you have a look at the (remarkably helpful) documentation that is available for the Razor mediator?

- http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/
- http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/downloads/detail?name=RazorMediatorDocumentation_v1.2.docx

These are full of examples that access the current Component and the Page. Just my 10 second search gives these fragments:

```
<body class=”@Page.Metadata.BodyClass”>

<div class=”@Component.Fields.NewsStyle”>

<img src=”@Fields.HeaderImage.ID” alt=”@Fields.HeaderImage.AltText” />
```

***Edit***: I see you added some more details in your follow-up comment. You might want to do as Bart suggests and add those details to the question. In the meantime, I'll spend a few more minutes searching the documentation for you.

The official documentation (the Word document I linked above), contains this example that seems to process metadata:

```
@foreach (var keyword in Publication.MetaData.SomeKeywordFields) {
    <li>@keyword.Title (@keyword.Id)</li>
}
```

The output of the Razor template will ***become*** the Output item in the Package. So it doesn't make any sense to use a Razor mediator to ***process*** the Output item. For that you might as well use a regular C# (fragment or assembly) TBB.

***Another edit***: It seems that the Razor mediator's implicit [`Fields`](http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.RazorMediator/Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.RazorMediator/TridionRazorTemplate.cs#87) variable always maps to the Component fields and the [`Metadata`](http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/source/browse/trunk/Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.RazorMediator/Tridion.Extensions.Mediators.RazorMediator/TridionRazorTemplate.cs#112) variable always maps to the Component's meatadata fields. I've linked the above names to the relevant fragments on Google code for your convenience.

So you seem to have two options:

1. detect whether you are in Page or Component (e.g. by looking at whether the implicit `Page` variable is `null` or not) and then have conditional expressions everywhere (`isInPage ? Page.Metadata : Metadata`)
2. fix this limitation of the [Razor mediator code](http://code.google.com/p/razor-mediator-4-tridion/source/checkout) yourself or hire [someone](http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/developers/alexander_klock.aspx) to fix it for you

Comment: Hi Frank, 
Thanks for your reply,
Actually, my problem is little different, as I written earlier, I am creating a TBB which will be used in both, Component Template and Page Template. 
I have created a TBB and its work fine in Component Template, but when I use this tbb in Page template, then its return me an error in “Component not found in this Context”, because, I am access Metadata value in this TBB. 
Is it possible can I use a single TBB in both, type of template?

Comment: Since the Razor mediator is an open-source project, did you consider simply looking at the source? And of course, worst case you can try/catch the exception and use that as an indication that you're ***not*** in a Component Template.

Comment: I have tried try/catch but, its search component Context. Because, by default, when i write Metadata.SomeFieldName then its accessing Metadata values for Component, and given the error for Page template, but when i written Page.Metadata.SomeFieldName then it works fine.

Comment: So, did you look at the source of the Razor mediator? I can do that for you, but given the amount of effort you've clearly already spent on this, it might also be something you're willing to do yourself.

Comment: You ***should*** also really add these additional details to your original question. You've received lots of down votes, most likely in part because the question didn't show any effort on your part. It turns out now that you have done more than the question originally suggested. So if you update the question, people may look more favorably on it. It also help to realize that most people here prefer debugging your code over debugging your prose. So share code, instead of describing what it does.

Comment: The @Metadata shortcut has been updated in Version 1.3 (thanks to this thread). It will now access Component.Metadata when the template type is a ComponentTemplate, and will access Page.Metadata when the template type is a PageTemplate.